# C loop to get strings and store them in 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, multidimensional-array, c-strings

I created a multi-dim array to store (name/fname/code) of multiple students in (row 0) it stores the (name/fname/code) of the first student then it passes to the next row (row 1) --> (name/fname/code) of the second student ... etc.

Every time I run the code and write a string when it reaches 9 character it will add 8 char of the next string
and if the next string reaches 9 char
it will add 8 char of the next string to it.

But if I write the name with just 8 char or less it runs like I want to.

If you didn't understand run the code and you will get it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  int i, nmbStud;

  int rows, columns;

  printf("Enter the number of students you want to add : ");
  scanf("%d", &nmbStud);

  char *arr[nmbStud][256];

  for (rows = 0; rows < nmbStud; rows++) {
    columns = 0;
    while (columns < 3) {

      printf("--Enter the %d name : ", rows + 1);
      scanf("%s", &arr[rows][columns]);

      columns++;

      printf("--Enter the %d family name : ", rows + 1);
      scanf("%s", &arr[rows][columns]);

      columns++;

      printf("--Enter the code of the student %d : ", rows + 1);
      scanf("%s", &arr[rows][columns]);

      columns++;
    }
  }

  for (rows = 0; rows < nmbStud; rows++) {
    for (columns = 0; columns < 3; columns++) {
      printf("-->%s\n", &arr[rows][columns]);
    }
  }
}
```

[Compile result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idpmo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is that you should correctly declare what you need and use it accordingly. Here `char *arr[nmbStud][256];` declares a Variable Length Array of pointers to characters. But later you use it with:

```
        scanf("%s",&arr[rows][columns]);
```

which stores the characters **inside** the pointer value. As you have a 64 bits system, a pointer uses 8 bytes, hence the problem when you try to use strings using more than 7 characters - do not forget the terminating null in C strings!

What you want should be closer to:

```
char arr[nmbStud][3][256]; // 2D VLA, size nmStud * 3, of strings of 255 characters
```

and later:

```
        scanf("%s",arr[rows][columns]);
```

And you should be aware that this code uses VLA which is an optional feature since C11 and that will not be accepted for example by Microsoft compilers...

---

But as the 3 strings contain different elements you'd better use structs here:

```
struct Student {
   char name[256];
   char fname[256];
   char code[256];
};
```

Comment: To avoid `gets()` like problems, suggest adding a _width_ to `scanf("%s"...`.